# Unable to pass an array by using expo router params

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I want to pass an array from one screen to another. So I pass the array like this,

```
const navigation = useRouter();
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
navigation.push({pathname: '/screen2', params: { carList: cars}})
```

and in the other screen(screen2) I do like this,

```
const response = useLocalSearchParams();
console.log(response.carList)
```

but in this screen I'm not receiving an array I'm receiving a string like this 'Saab,Volvo,BMW'
and I cannot access the items like response.carList[0].

Answer (score 2):

For now I am using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` for passing data as array.

Pushing data:

```
router.push({
  pathname: '/(tabs)/planner/create',
  params: {
    categories: JSON.stringify(selectedItems),
  },
})
```

Receiving data:

```
const params = useLocalSearchParams<>()
const categories = JSON.parse(params.categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by:

```js
import { useLocalSearchParams } from "expo-router";

// this should be inside screen2 component
const params = useLocalSearchParams();
```

now you can access params.carList

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dinamic page that will open an specific profile of an id, from the id that you are sending, example:

```
<Link
    href={{
              pathname: "/pages/[id]",
              params: { id : idService },
            }}
 > Text Link </Link>
```

Or you can just sent a var to another page:

```
<Link
    href={{
              pathname: "/home/profile",
              params: { id : idService, nameService: "Name Service" },
            }}
 > Text Link </Link>
```

In the page that you receive the params:

```
import { useLocalSearchParams } from 'expo-router'
const DetailPage = () => {
const {params} = useLocalSearchParams();
console.log(params.id);
}
export default DetailPage;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

normaly i use the useNavigation() hook from @react-navigation/native, try this:

ex:

```
  type Routes = {
   routeNames: never[];
  }; 

  type NavigationProps = {
  navigate: (name: string, params?: { [key: string]: any }) => void;
  goBack: () => void;
  reset: (index: number, routeNames: Routes[]) => void;
  addListener: (v1: string, v2: any) => void;
 };

 const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationProps>();
  <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={0.7}
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate('screen2', {
          cars: cars,
        })
      }
  >....
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: The question is about `expo router` not `react-navigation`